# C++ .Net style buttons with Win32

Tags: c++, .net, winapi, button, styles

I was wondering about the Win32 button styles. Since VS2012, we have had the option to make "flat" style buttons, drop downs, etc. on .Net based forms (like this one, although that's not the color set I would use: http://assets.componentowl.com/screenshots/36/flat-style_original_1328267962.png?1328242762). Is there a way to create those styles of controls through the Win32 API, or would I have to custom render it?

Comment: The FlatStyle property goes all the way back to .NET 1.0, VS2002.  Yes, it uses a custom renderer.

Comment: So, there is no Win32 property/argument I can use to display a button like that?